# gcloud CLI authentication using service account on GitHub Codespaces

Tags: environment-variables, gcloud

I'd like to authenticate to `gcloud` CLI took from GitHub Codespaces devcontainer. I can setup GitHub Codespaces secrets to expose `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, and I can assign it the actual service account value (JSON content).

But, the `gcloud` CLI [expects it to be a path to a file](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_variable). What is considered a best-practice to deal with that?

Thanks,

Comment: Save the credentials to a file with the `.json` extension. Set an env variable to point to the location of the file: `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/your/file.json"`. Don't save this file to version control.

Comment: What is the best way to achieve that in an automatic way, for GitHub Codespaces / general devcontainers?

Comment: Even with Federated Workload Identity (more about that [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/enable-keyless-access-to-gcp-with-workload-identity-federation)) you still need the env. var. `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to point to a JSON config. file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure if there are best practices for these patterns yet, but I’ve found success with creating a Codespace secret that contains the text of a file and writing it to a file in the Codespace using a [lifecycle script](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference#_lifecycle-scripts) such as `postCreateCommand`.

```json
{
  “postCreateCommand”: “echo -e \"$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDENTIALS\" > /path/to/your/file.json”
}
```

*Note: I usually don’t call this command from directly within `devcontainer.json`, I create a separate bash script and execute that instead.*

From there you should be able to interact with the file normally. I’ve successfully used this pattern for SSH keys, kubeconfigs, and AWS credentials.

Answer (score 0):

you can have service account key JSON in environment variable like `GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS` (this name is in fact used by Terraform provider) and then authorize gcloud CLI like so:

```
gcloud auth login --cred-file /dev/stdin  <<<"$GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS" --quiet
```

Note, this will save contents of the `GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS` into usual place under

```
~/.config/gcloud
```